# using math with XMLHttpRequest data (still dont get it)

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest

I have been asked if I can use some form data and present it in HTML.

I need to add up the LOADS data/values and multiply it by the RATE data/values, I thought this would have worked but its not showing anything in my browser?

Where am I going wrong?

I'm new to JavaScript and I have HTML/CSS skills. I know jQuery is probably the best way to do this sort of stuff but I don't know it.

thanks to Kolink yesterday who told me to use textContent or innerText and to convert to numbers using (parseInt or parseFloat ), - still stumped though :-(

```
<html>
<body>

<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","xmltest.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 



var i;
// array loads data from xml//
var data = [xmlDoc.x[1].getElementsByTagName("RATE").innerText, xmlDoc.x[1].getElementsByTagName("LOADS").innerText];

// Loop cycles through array converts to numbers, writes array value //
for (i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    parseFloat(data[i]);
    document.write("<tr ><td>");
    document.write(data[i]);
    document.write("</td><tr>");
}
// data array multipled//
var total = (data[0] * data[1])

{ 
  document.write("<tr ><td>");
  document.write(total);
  document.write("</td><tr>");
  }



</script>

</body>
</html>




xml

XML file

<MULTILOAD_TICKET>
<TICKET>
<DATE>12/11/12</DATE>
<ADDRESS>123 FAKE STREET</ADDRESS>
<RATE>300</RATE>
<LOADS>3</LOADS>
<CUSTOMER>Columbia Ales</CUSTOMER>
<ORDERID>BBKHJ1001</ORDERID>
<DRIVER>BOB</DRIVER>
<VEHICAL_REG>UJ78 JHE</VEHICAL_REG>
<MATERIAL>SPOIL</MATERIAL>
<SIG>URL</SIG>
</TICKET>

<TICKET>
<DATE>12/11/12</DATE>
<ADDRESS>123 FAKE STREET</ADDRESS>
<RATE>300</RATE>
<LOADS>6</LOADS>
<CUSTOMER>Columbia Ales</CUSTOMER>
<ORDERID>BBKHJ1001</ORDERID>
<DRIVER>JACK</DRIVER>
<VEHICAL_REG>EU78 JHD</VEHICAL_REG>
<MATERIAL>SPOIL</MATERIAL>
<SIG>URL</SIG>
</TICKET>

<TICKET>
<DATE>15/11/12</DATE>
<ADDRESS>123 FAKE STREET</ADDRESS>
<RATE>300</RATE>
<LOADS>5</LOADS>
<CUSTOMER>Columbia Ales</CUSTOMER>
<ORDERID>BBKHJ1001</ORDERID>
<DRIVER>BOB</DRIVER>
<VEHICAL_REG>UJ78 JHE</VEHICAL_REG>
<MATERIAL>SPOIL</MATERIAL>
<SIG>URL</SIG>
</TICKET>

</MULTILOAD_TICKET>
```

Comment: What does your XML look like?

Comment: It's there at the bottom just several tags but I only want to multiply two of them

Answer (score 0):

Here, try reading this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started. You must listen to the readystate change event of the xmlHttpRequest and when it's successful, then you parse the XML.